# Android Application minimize issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have developed an Xamarin forms application. In Android devices, Lenovo K6(v7.0) and Nexus 6 (v7.1.1), when the app is minimized and opened by clicking the app icon the opening page of the application is reset to default instead of showing the part in the page where the user has minimized the application. But, when the app is minimized and re-opened using the recently opened tabs it is resumed correctly.

This problem arises only in the mentioned two devices in all other devices the page is resumed from where it is minimized when the user re-opens the application on using both recent tabs or App icon click. If the close application then reopens it and application starts from Splash screen. In above scenario, the app starts with the home page and reset as default launch. I have started the download of my app and progressing the download. I have minimized the app and click app icon from the installed app on the device. Now, progress is reset and file stays as download file.

Please suggest on this to resolve it.

Regards,

Cheran

Comment: i'm also facing this issue are u found then pls share...